# How to use Row_Number() correctly

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm running the following query on `Postgres`:

```
SELECT a.testscoreid,
       COUNT(a.*) AS Questions,
       a.created,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Questions) AS Number,
       b.irt_tlevel
FROM asmt.testscores a
  JOIN asmt.questions b ON a.questionid = b.questionid
WHERE a.answered = TRUE
AND   a.testscoreid = '53bd6ed5da2cfe7baf0d97ed'
AND   irt_tlevel IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY a.testscoreid,
         a.created,
         b.irt_tlevel
ORDER BY Questions DESC,
         a.created ASC
```

which gives me the following result:

```
Testscoreid                 Questions Created               Number irt_tlevel
53bd6ed5da2cfe7baf0d97ed    272       2014-07-09 09:33:25.0 1      easy
53bd6ed5da2cfe7baf0d97ed    38        2014-07-09 09:33:25.0 1      hard
53bd6ed5da2cfe7baf0d97ed    34        2014-07-09 09:33:25.0 1      medium
```

I would like to have the `Number` column increment each time, for all `questionid`. I think I'm missing something in `row_number()`.

I want the column Number to increment for all the questionid. For example - I would like to have 272 rows (with incrementing Number) for easy questions in the example above, 38 rows for hard and 34 rows for medium. In total, I would like to have (272+38+34) rows, with `Number` incrementing as per `Created`.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm surprised that you can use the alias `Questions` in the windowing clause.  It makes sense from an order-of-processing perspective (`row_number()` is logically executed after the `group by`), but SQL Server and Oracle don't support the use of an alias in that context.

Comment: It seems that you actually want (272+38+34) rows in your output, why do you GROUP them then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to show (272 + 38 + 34) rows? What you expect is not clear.
If you want such rows your main error is grouping with irt_tlevel level.

But if you do so to get the total count for a particular level you may have to have a sub query or a function call to get the total.

e.g.- (not tested for syntax errors)

```
SELECT a.testscoreid,       
       a.created,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY created ) AS Number,
       b.irt_tlevel irt_level
FROM asmt.testscores a, asmt.questions b
WHERE a.answered = TRUE
AND b.questionid = a.questionid
AND   a.testscoreid = '53bd6ed5da2cfe7baf0d97ed'
ORDER BY a.created ASC
```

Comment: Then you dont need COUNT(a.*) AS Questions right? because it is always 1. And how the 'Number ' should looks like?

Comment: Correct, we can then remove the `count(*)`. I just want the number to increment according to `created`. So higher dates get higher `Number`

Comment: See the edited answer. I am still not sure if this exactly you want. Also you should be able to think about an efficient way for the subquery.

Comment: Well, this is new `[Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: This type of correlated subquery pattern is not supported due to internal error;`

Comment: Sorry to hear that. I think what you need is fairly very simple query. I removed all the group bys. What do you try to achieve from group by? I cant write an correct answer without knowing you table schema :(.

Comment: Glad to help you. When you ask a question specially related to SQL, what you have to show is what you expect. Otherwise it is hard to come up with a good answer without knowing the schema and relationships. So if you clearly ask what you needed without the additional columns you specified, it would have been much easier and straight forward to answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ORDER BY` instead of `PARTITION BY`:

```
SELECT a.testscoreid,
       COUNT(*) AS Questions,
       a.created,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) AS Number,
       b.irt_tlevel
```

Comment: Perhaps I should have been more clear. I want the column `Number` to increment for all the `questionid`. For example - I would like to have 272 rows (with incrementing `Number`) for `easy` questions in the example above, 38 rows for `hard` and 34 rows for `medium`.

Comment: @Patthebug: in that case, duplicate the `order by` at the end of the query, f.e. `row_number() over (order by Questions DESC, a.created ASC)`

Comment: @Patthebug: I guess you didn't remove your `partition by` clause?

Comment: @Patthebug: If you have a `row_number` without `partition by`, you can't have two rows with number 1. See if you can reproduce the problem at [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com)

Comment: @Andomar - The `Number` column has changed to 1,2,3. I'm looking for (272+38+34) rows with `Number` incrementing each time.